# Display all rows of data from both tables even though conditions exist

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that is from two tables but I need some help in expanding the results.

The query I am running is:

```
SELECT 
    B.OBJ_FULL, B.SUBJ_FULL, B.ACT_YTD_TY, 
    SUM(A.JNL_VALUE) AS JNL_TOTAL
FROM 
    DB2ADM2.JNLFILE A 
INNER JOIN 
    DB2ADM2.TFINCATP B ON B.OBJ_FULL = A.JNL_OBJ
                       AND B.SUBJ_FULL = A.JNL_SUBJ
WHERE 
    A.JNL_YEAR ='15'
    AND A.JNL_PROCESSED ='N'
    AND OBJ_FULL = 'TBBBB'
GROUP BY 
    B.OBJ_FULL, B.SUBJ_FULL, B.ACT_YTD_TY
```

The data being returned is:

```
OBJ_FULL SUBJ_FULL  ACT_YTD_TY  JNL_TOTAL
-----------------------------------------
TBBBB    9404       -9666.73    -547.78
TBBBB    9405       -13098.05   -24.39
```

I have now split the query above into two separate queries to show the data that is being returned for each one.

Query 1 - Journal values not processed this week on code TBBBB

```
SELECT 
    JNL_OBJ, JNL_SUBJ, SUM(JNL_VALUE) AS JNL_VALUE
FROM 
    DB2ADM2.JNLFILE
WHERE 
    JNL_YEAR ='15'
    AND JNL_PROCESSED ='N'
    AND JNL_OBJ = 'TBBBB'
GROUP BY 
    JNL_OBJ, JNL_SUBJ
```

Results on Query 1

```
JNL_OBJ JNL_SUBJ  JNL_VALUE
---------------------------
TBBBB   9404      -547.78
TBBBB   9405      -24.39
```

Query 2 - Year to date values on code TBBBB

```
SELECT 
    OBJ_FULL, SUBJ_FULL, ACT_YTD_TY
FROM 
    DB2ADM2.TFINCATP 
WHERE  
    OBJ_FULL = 'TBBBB'
```

Results on Query 2

```
OBJ_FULL  SUBJ_FULL  ACT_YTD_TY
-------------------------------
TBBBB     3420     12000
TBBBB     3473     18453.02
TBBBB     3524     2480.4
TBBBB     3704     585
TBBBB     6812     0 
TBBBB     6910     0
TBBBB     7704     -4142.71
TBBBB     8199     -25
TBBBB     9400     -168363.1
TBBBB     9403     -457.56
TBBBB     9404     -9666.73
TBBBB     9405     -13098.05
TBBBB     9812     0
```

The result I am looking for is query 2 with an additional column from query 1 this being the JNL_VALUE, however as every TBBBB code does not have a journal each week, only the rows with a journal are currently being returned, the column must insert a 0 if a present value is not there.

Any ideas how I do that please?

Comment: What type of SQL? SQL Server? MySQL? Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a zero when there is no A record matching a B one:

```
SELECT B.OBJ_FULL, B.SUBJ_FULL, B.ACT_YTD_TY, isnull(A.JNL_VALUE, 0) AS JNL_VALUE
FROM DB2ADM2.JNLFILE A 
Right Outer JOIN DB2ADM2.TFINCATP B ON B.OBJ_FULL = A.JNL_OBJ
AND B.SUBJ_FULL = A.JNL_SUBJ
WHERE A.JNL_YEAR ='15'
AND A.JNL_PROCESSED ='N'
AND OBJ_FULL = 'TBBBB'
```

(Do a search on Outer joins: there are Left, Right, and Full outer joins.) Since you want every B row, then I've removed the Group By. and put in the Right Outer Join to get all B's even when there is no matching A.

Comment: Tweaked it a little bit but that now works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` here and restrict that `JNLFILE` table in the `ON` clause of the JOIN, so you don't filter results after the join, but before (which you could also accomplish in a subquery):

```
     SELECT B.OBJ_FULL,
    B.SUBJ_FULL,
    B.ACT_YTD_TY,
   COALESCE(SUM(A.JNL_VALUE), 0) AS JNL_TOTAL
FROM DB2ADM2.TFINCATP B
 LEFT OUTER JOIN DB2ADM2.JNLFILE A ON 
    B.OBJ_FULL = A.JNL_OBJ AND
    B.SUBJ_FULL = A.JNL_SUBJ AND
    A.JNL_YEAR = '15' AND
    A.JNL_PROCESSED = 'N'
WHERE B.OBJ_FULL = 'TBBBB'
GROUP BY B.OBJ_FULL,
    B.SUBJ_FULL,
    B.ACT_YTD_TY
```

You can think of `TFINCATP` as being your "Driver" table that then just picks up values from the `JNLFILE` table to which we LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Couldn't quite get that to work but thanks for your reply.